# getelementptr llvm ir instruction arguments

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, instructions

I'm working on a toy compiler and I'm trying to generate llvm ir bytecode and the exe compiling it with clang.
I've a simple question: I searched on google some information about the `getelementptr`, but I can't understand why I've to pass two `i32` or `i64` consts as last two arguments.
For example:
In global scope:

```cpp
@string = constant [4 x i8] c"abc\00"
```

In function scope:

```cpp
;result now contains the value of @string
;     instruction | type of result | pointer to @string | what are these two i32 0?
%result = getelementptr [4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @string, i32 0, i32 0
```

Comment: Have you read [The Often Misunderstood GEP Instruction](https://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html)? Anyway, the first 0 is there because `@string` is a *pointer* to an array and the second 0 is there because we want a pointer to the character at index 0 of the array.

Comment: ok thank you, you said the last 0 means the char at index 0, but after that instruction %result will anyway contain all the string

Comment: `%result` will contain the address of the first character as an `i8*`. If you pass such a pointer to a function expecting a C-string, it represents the whole string (because a C string is considered to be the sequence of characters starting at the pointed-to character upto the following 0 byte).